# How to convert mcrypt_generic to openssl_encrypt?

Tags: php, php-openssl

this is my php code in PHP7.0.30

```
    $key = strtoupper(md5('799ae002c7e940ef8a890b3a428f8f458e3f7c39d1cc2bf24390f0c46cf932c8'));
    $text ='name=王星星&mobile=15212345678&idNumber=620402198709215456&bankName=招商银行&bankNum=6214830100799652';
    $plaintext = $text;
    $size = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    //PKCS5Padding
    $padding = $size - strlen($plaintext) % $size;
    $plaintext .= str_repeat(chr($padding), $padding);
    $module = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, '', MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, '');
    $iv = str_repeat("\0", $size);
    /* Intialize encryption */
    mcrypt_generic_init($module, base64_decode($key), $iv);
    /* Encrypt data */
    $encrypted = mcrypt_generic($module, $plaintext);
    /* Terminate encryption handler */
    mcrypt_generic_deinit($module);
    mcrypt_module_close($module);
    var_dump(base64_encode($encrypted));

    /* openssl_encrypt */
    $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, 'AES-256-CBC',base64_decode($key), OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING,$iv);
    var_dump(base64_encode($encrypted));
```

mcrypt_generic output: `8LZZEXRhAfeeQOxF1iI9GpBcA2hSCelrUq2OimhSgZly6RfRonzGiE32vHh/JkdK+X5N5hFBMKz+iOmWAbgL9BIu2GIAxBIXCOusxFU4eDJ/5uy7F9vR9EE5NqOAiHBZhTP3pzMtEc0fLAzg8Tsngg==`

but openssl_encrypt output:
`g/YBzu+SGy9jfR+DIVY2S0iGM2O0QEs+J3IEv7bNAoz7+3iX9FboJZT0h+OH6uUeQBoSsD+eAga69U5C86Ibcp5Q2ay1FzfDFG/eGBtUaAJxRBwhxiNeBxPw2jBar2fR42wZUZOGTjlT5Ujgz+s/Iw==`

I don't know how to convert mcrypt_generic to openssl_encrypt , thanks!

Comment: Have you tried AES-128-CBC in your openssl encrypt?

Comment: Yes AES-128-CBC output: `VLhp06g+RtAuQN0RHOyd/HRuBQzvqOTvk4orxvX7F3f709bNgOfmd7JQ+m167eh/MpLws3lSl4kyAPEy0ZEtN62+BjX3zZ1d/8Bt9rf1whDWGI566lVfe5B9kwQ8fJpa2wO94TfPyM1QNVJBEocdgg==`

Comment: I found that if I change `base64_decode($key)` to `$key`,It can get same output .but I must use `base64_decode($key)`,beacause It transform from JAVA.

Comment: Are you stuck with that key or can you change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a 256 bit key.  Your current "key" is 32 bytes which is 256 bits.

You problem is that your are decoding the key.  When you decode the key you are reducing the key's size to 24 bytes or 192 bits.

So you have two options.

Increase the key size by another 8 bytes before you `base64_encode()` it.

OR

Just remove the `base64_decode()` functions.

Secondly, I hope you are using the md5 for testing purposes and not for your application.  The md5 hash is not suited to give you a hash that is designed for modern cryptography.

You should use something like `$key = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($size);` to generate a key with.

I would also like to point you in the direction of the [Libsodium](https://paragonie.com/book/pecl-libsodium) library.  It is now native on the latest version of PHP.

***UPDATED***

If your goal is to have AES encryption with a 256 bit key like your code suggest, then you will have to do what I stated above.  If that is not one of your requirements then the only thing you have to do is change the `AES-256-CBC` to `AES-192-CBC` in the `openssl_encrypt()` function like so.

```
$encrypted = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, 'AES-192-CBC', base64_decode($key), OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, $iv);
```

One thing to point out is that the "128" in the name `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` refers to the block size not the key size, where as the "256" in `AES-256-CBC` actually refers to the key size.  Which is why the `AES-192-CBC` will work for your current key size of 192 bits.  AES encryption uses a standard of a 128 bit block size, so that is compatible the `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` block size.

Cheers

Comment: Or specify a key size of 192-bits, that isa a legal AES key size.

Comment: @zaph Thank you for you comment.  You are completely correct.  I have updated my answer to be more specific.  Please note that my answer was perfectly correct and in line with the OP's question.  The only way the OP was was going to achieve `AES-256-CBC` is with a 256 bit key. I do not think it should have warranted a down vote.

Comment: @Joseph_J Thanks!

Comment: Yup, no problem, hope your project works out. Cheers!